# How to formatter a number in a chart

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my chart, I have several values except that the formatting isn't correct.

For example: I have a figure `15900`, I would like to get the following format: `15 900`, I want a space between thousands and hundreds.

I would like to create the spacing below please:

```
chart.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:MM ";
        chart.numberFormatter.numberFormat = "#.#a ";
        chart.numberFormatter.bigNumberPrefixes = [
            { "number": 1e+0, "suffix": " " }
        ];
```

I look on the doc but I don't find what I want.

https://docs.amcharts.com/javascriptcharts/AmChart#numberFormatter

Answer (score 1):

Edit According to the [doc](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/formatting-date-time-and-numbers-using-intl-object/#Setting_numberformat) for version 4 you should use

```
chart.numberFormatter.numberFormat = "#' '###";
```

Keep in mind though that the link that you have provided is for an older version of  charts v2, while the code you try to use is for current version 4.

Comment: my number is displayed twice with `#`
example -> 39.7##39.7

Comment: @elodie check the version of amChart that you currently use

Comment: In the file `package.json`, I have the version -> `@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.10.20",`

Comment: @elodie check my updated answer `"#' '###"`

Comment: It gives me the numbers 2 times for example, if I have `3426.5` with` "# '' ###"; `, the display is ` 3426.5  3426.5 ` instead of ` 3 426.5`. :-(